# Pandas - Iterate dataframe and update each row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to iterate the data frame and update each row but it doesn't add up. The logic is when the keyword match any of the string inside skill_list `['java', 'sql', 'oracle', 'json']`, then update with the score.

final_database

```
                          Subject       Keyword Count  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer      android      2  
1  Mobile_Application_Developer          sql      1  
2  Mobile_Application_Developer         java      1  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer           N/A     0  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer          sql      3  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer          sql      2  
1  Mobile_Application_Developer         java      4  
2  Mobile_Application_Developer  engineering      2  
3  Mobile_Application_Developer   javascript      1  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer           N/A     0  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer           N/A     0  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer  engineering      1  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer           N/A     0  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer     building      1  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer  engineering      2  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer           N/A     0  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer  engineering      1  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer           N/A     0
```

Code

```
skill= "java:4,sql:3,oracle:2,json:4"
keyword_list = re.split(',', skill)
skill_list = []
total_score = 0

for x in range(len(keyword_list)):
    lang = re.split(':', keyword_list[x]) 

    skill_list.append(lang[0])
    total_score = total_score + int(lang[1]) 

for index, row in final_database.iterrows():

    for x in range(len(keyword_list)):
        lang = re.split(':', keyword_list[x]) 

        if row['Keyword'].strip() in skill_list:
            final_database.set_value(index,'Score',lang[1])
```

updated final_database

```
                          Subject       Keyword Count Score  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer      android      2     4  
1  Mobile_Application_Developer          sql      1     4  
2  Mobile_Application_Developer         java      1     4  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer           N/A     0     4  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer          sql      3     4  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer          sql      2     4  
1  Mobile_Application_Developer         java      4     4  
2  Mobile_Application_Developer  engineering      2     4  
3  Mobile_Application_Developer   javascript      1   NaN  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer           N/A     0     4  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer           N/A     0     4  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer  engineering      1     4  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer           N/A     0     4  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer     building      1     4  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer  engineering      2     4  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer           N/A     0     4  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer  engineering      1     4  
0  Mobile_Application_Developer           N/A     0     4
```

Comment: Please make explicit (ie, describe) what your objective is in moving from the first to the final dataframe.

Comment: "it doesn't add up" This is not clear. Please post what is your actual and predicted output is.

Comment: What is your logic here?

Comment: `set_value` is depricated. Use `iat` instead.

Comment: `skill = {'java':4, 'sql':3, 'oracle':2, 'json':4}; df['Score'] = df['Keyword'].map(skill)`?

Comment: @Chris  please check updated question

Comment: @MohammadNurdin why does `engineering`, `building` and `N/A` have a score of 4 when it is not in the skill list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```py
skill= "java:4,sql:3,oracle:2,json:4"

skill_map=dict(map(lambda x: x.split(":"), skill.split(",")))

df["Score"]=df["Keyword"].str.strip().map(skill_map).fillna(0)
```

Outputs:

```py
                         Subject      Keyword Count Score
0   Mobile_Application_Developer      android     2     0
1   Mobile_Application_Developer          sql     1     3
2   Mobile_Application_Developer         java     1     4
3   Mobile_Application_Developer          N/A     0     0
4   Mobile_Application_Developer          sql     3     3
5   Mobile_Application_Developer          sql     2     3
6   Mobile_Application_Developer         java     4     4
7   Mobile_Application_Developer  engineering     2     0
8   Mobile_Application_Developer   javascript     1     0
9   Mobile_Application_Developer          N/A     0     0
10  Mobile_Application_Developer          N/A     0     0
11  Mobile_Application_Developer  engineering     1     0
12  Mobile_Application_Developer          N/A     0     0
13  Mobile_Application_Developer     building     1     0
14  Mobile_Application_Developer  engineering     2     0
15  Mobile_Application_Developer          N/A     0     0
16  Mobile_Application_Developer  engineering     1     0
17  Mobile_Application_Developer          N/A     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to `map` the keyword to the score.

[Pandas Map Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
keyword_mapping={'java':4, 'sql':3, 'oracle':2, 'json':4}

final_database['score']=final_database.keyword.str.lower().map(keyword_mapping)
```

Explanation:
I've taken the dataframe final_database and have taken the keyword column which is a series. I get the lowercased value using [pandas string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html) in this case `lower`

Then I've applied map using a dictionary of the keys (keywords) and their corresponding values (scores)

Answer (score 0):

```
skills =  {'java':4,
            'sql': 3,
           'oracle' : 2, 
           'json':4}
df['score'] = df.loc[df['Keyword']].map(skills)
```

Comment: While this may answer the OP's question, please provide a description of your solution to make it clear *how* it solves the problem. This will make the answer more valuable for future readers.